# Context not the same when using in different projects Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have ddl that contains the whole logic of the whole application including the DatabaseContext.

When i make a query by a console application everything **works just fine** but when i make a query from a MVC application and consumes the same ddl, then a lot of errors are being thrown like invalid table name or invalid column name.

If i do this in console application works as expected

```
Batches.Search(x=>x.ForWho == 4);
```

But if i do the same thing in the mvc application everything fail(the errors i mentioned before)

Why is this happening?

The target project of both are .net framework 4.5.

Comment: You should provide more information/code.

Comment: What more can i say? I have nothing more in mind to tell. Can you point me out what kind of information you want?

Comment: SSCCE  http://www.sscce.org/

Or at least some more code from your dll and application, it is unclear how exactly you are doing it, so it is hard to say what might cause the problem.

Comment: Are you using database-first/model-first (with EDMX file) or code-first (without EDMX file)? Are the connection strings in the console app project and in the web app project the same (not in the dll project, that connection string is not used, if there is any at all)?